# notifydatasetchange to expandableListView android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, notifydatasetchanged

I am using ExpandableListView to show my data.

but when I perform some operation in ChildView of expandableListView that time I want to update my ExpandableListView as per my new data.

I have tried expandableListview.notifyDataSetChanged();
at that time it will collapse all parents in ExpandableListView.

I want to update my ExpandableListview without collapsing and want to update my ExpandableListview.

Comment: you could maintain the position that was expanded, and thus when calling notifydata set changed, also call expandgroup method and pass the position of the group. That way even if it closes it will expand the group. else all the groups will collapse

Comment: @DharaShah : I also did that but when I set particular position in to expadable list view it will go on first position.
I don't want that.
I just want to stay view as it is when I clicked on child view.

Comment: then u cud also mention scrolltoPosition in ur code and specify the parent position atleast.